# Describing $\Bbb{Z}$ in set notation

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to describe $\Bbb{Z}$ in set notation in terms of  $\Bbb{N}$ and $0$.  Does this look right?  I know $\Bbb{Z}$ is all positives, negatives, and zero, but does that work on $\Bbb{N}$?

ℤ={x∈ℕ|x≥0 and x≤0}

Comment: Presumably you mean $\Bbb N = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$.  At any rate, be careful with your notation: which $x \in \Bbb N$ satisfy $x \leq 0$?

Comment: You have just described either the empty set or $\{0\}$, depending on whether or not you take $0 \in \mathbb N$. What you wrote can be read as "The set of all $x$ in $\mathbb N$ such that $x$ is greater than or equal to zero and $x$ is less than or equal to zero. Clearly, the only integer satisfying this is zero, which may or may not be natural, depending on how you define the natural numbers. Try perhaps instead $\mathbb Z = \mathbb N \cup \{-x \mid x \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: The only way I've seen $\mathbb{Z}$ described in terms of $\mathbb{N}$ is through equivalence classes of $\mathbb{N}$. But again this was in the context of trying to construct the integers

Answer (score 2):

No, this suggestion is not good.

$\Bbb Z$ is a superset of $\Bbb N$. This means that it has *more* elements. Whenever you define a set as $\{x\in\Bbb N\mid \ldots\}$ you effectively require the defined set to be a *subset* of $\Bbb N$.

Moreover, if $x\leq 0$ **and** $x\geq 0$, then it is necessarily the case that $x=0$. Therefore you have defined $\{0\}$.

**HINT:** Recall that $x\in\Bbb Z$ if and only if $|x|\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: That looks as if $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I didn't like it either, but I'm struggling how to define $\Bbb{Z}$ in terms of $\Bbb{N}$ and $0$.  Would this work:


ℤ={x∈ℤ| |x|∈N or x=0}

The text doesn't state if N includes 0 or not

Comment: @westhe32nd: Well, yes, but it would be circular. If you have $\Bbb Z$, why not defined it as $\{x\in\Bbb Z\mid x=x\}$? I suppose that you are looking to define $\Bbb Z$ inside a larger set than itself.

Comment: Ah!  Dumb mistake on my part.  If I replaced Z with N, and kept everything else that would work?

Comment: @westhe32nd: No. Read my answer again. In particular the second sentence. Perhaps review again what does it mean when we write $\{x\in X\mid\varphi(x)\}$.